How does one learn to use Ansicht?
According to DWDS Ansicht is sometimes declined as genitive (predicative genitives) and sometimes not:


einer Ansicht beipflichten, huldigen, Ausdruck verleihen
(jmdm.) seine Ansichten darlegen, unterbreiten
wir sind (also) derselben Ansicht
das ist meine persönliche, eigene Ansicht


I find this assortment of declencions quite confusing. Is there any way to make sense of it? Does one need to memorize all the odd-ball fixed phrases associated with Ansicht, and then assume all other verbs can be associated with standard declencions? Or what?

Since the case depends mostly on the verb, it is not surprising that some noun can appear in several cases.

Yes, the pearl I take from this exchange is that, in German, the verb is the primary engine driving case in the sentence -- something I had not previously sufficiently internalized.

A nominal group is a noun plus some words that stand nearby and are directly connected to that noun, like articles, adjectives and similar words. Here are the nominal groups taken from your question, all of which containing a grammatical form of the noun Ansicht:

einer Ansicht
seine Ansicht
derselben Ansicht
meine persönliche, eigene Ansicht

The last examples contains a possessive pronoun (meine) and a list of adjectives (persönliche, eigene) whose elements are separated from each other by commas. But all four words are together one nominal group.
The grammatical case of a nominal group depends on ...

whether the nominal group is an attribute of another noun
the preposition if the nominal group is part of a prepositional group
the main verb of the sentence or clause otherwise

I'll explain all these possibilities later, but lets first talk about your concrete examples.

einer Ansicht beipflichten = to agree with a view
einer Ansicht huldigen = to pay homage to a view
einer Ansicht Ausdruck verleihen = to express a view (literally: to give expression to a view)

The verbs beipflichten, huldigen and verleihen need all a dative object, and this dative object is in all three examples »einer Ansicht«. (The verb verleihen (to give, to award, to confer) needs also an accusative object, which here is »Ausdruck« = expression)

jemandem seine Ansichten darlegen = to present/express one's view to someone
jemandem seine Ansichten unterbreiten = to present/express one's view to someone

Both verbs darlegen and unterbreiten need two objects. The object that says to whom something is presented must be in dative case, this is jemandem in the given example. The object, that contains the thing or idea that is presented must be in accusative case. In both sentences of the example this accusative object is »seine Ansicht«.

wir sind (also) derselben Ansicht = we are (therefore) of the same opinion

The phrases »einer Ansicht sein« (to be of an opinion) and »derselben Ansicht sein« (to be of the same opinion) are fixed phrases. Fixed phrases are made with outdated grammar that has become invalid many centuries ago, but for some specific combinations of words is still used. Such fixed phrases with odd grammar exist also in English (example: "I know not", "So be it"). In this phrase the part »einer Ansicht« is in genitive case. The word Ansicht can be replaced by a few synonyms in this phrase like Meinung or Überzeugung. Also possible but rare is »eines Glaubens sein«. (Der Glaube is masculine, all other synonyms mentioned here are feminine.)

Das ist meine persönliche, eigene Ansicht.

This is a full sentence (all other examples were not) and the verb of this sentence is a form of sein (to be) which is a copula. I explain copulas in more detail down below. You should just know, that a copula wants what looks like an object (but technically isn't) to be in nominative case.

What influences the grammatical case of a nominal group?
Attribute of another noun
If a nominal group (here: des Gärtners) is used as an attribute of another noun (here: Hütte), it is always in genitive case.

Die Hütte des Gärtners ist aus Holz.
The hut of the gardener is made of wood. (This is the best translation, but it still uses a different grammatical pattern.)
Des Gärtners Hütte ist aus Holz.
The gardener's hut is made of wood. (English and German use the same grammatical pattern.)

(Note, that attributes of nouns can also be prepositional groups which are not nominal groups. See next section.)
Part of a prepositional group
A prepositional group begins with a preposition and the rest of it is a nominal group. The case of a nominal group depends on the preposition, and in case of two-way-prepositions it also depends on whether a place or a direction is meant.
Some prepositions (like trotz, während, kraft, dank and many more) need their nominal group to be in genitive case:

Sandra fährt während der Nacht.
Sandra drives during the night.

Some other prepositions (like aus, mit, von, zu and many more) need their nominal group to be in dative case:

Sandra fährt mit dem Auto.
Sandra drives with the car.
Die Hütte von dem Gärtner ist aus Holz.
The hut of the gardener is made of wood.

Another group of prepositions (like durch, für, gegen, ohne and many more) need their nominal group to be in accusative case:

Sandra fährt durch den Wald.
Sandra drives through the forest.

The trickiest group of prepositions are two-way-prepositions (German name: "Wechselpräpositionen") (like in, auf, über, vor and many more). They need dative case if they mean a place but accusative case if they mean a direction:

place = dative (Sandra is in the city all the time, neither entering nor leaving it)

Sandra fährt in der Stadt.
Sandra drives in (inside) the city.


direction = accusative (Sandra is going to enter the city, she was outside before.)

Sandra fährt in die Stadt.
Sandra drives in (into) the city.




Dependence of main verb
German verbs can't stand alone. They rule the sentence (the main verb is the king of its sentence), so they need some other things to rule. These other things are the subject, objects and things that look and behave like objects at first glance, but aren't.

Subject
Every German verb needs a subject. (Commands (»Renn weg!« = Run away!) are common exceptions. There are even other exceptions (»Mich friert.« = I feel cold.), but they are very rare.) And every subject is always in nominative case.

Das Kind schläft.
The child is sleeping.


genitive object
A small group of German verbs need an object in genitive case.

Der Gärtner wurde des Mordes angeklagt.
The gardener was accused of murder.


dative object
The group of verbs that need a dative object is quite large.

Dieser Mantel gehört dem Mann.
This coat belongs to (is owned by) the man.


accusative object
There are also a lot of verbs that need accusative objects.

Ich sehe den Mann.
I see the man.


nominative of equality (Gleichsetzungsnominativ)
This looks like an object, and it even behaves like an object in some extend, but technically it is different. Verbs that need this nominative of equality are called copulae (German: Kopulas or Kopulae) (singular: copula, German: Kopula). These verbs are sein (to be), werden (to become) and bleiben (to stay).

Der Gärtner ist der Mörder.
The gardener is the murderer.



(Note, that many verbs need two or three objects, often in different cases, and some verb need prepositional objects (»Der Fahrer achtet auf den Verkehr.« = »The driver pays attention to the traffic.«) which by themselves are in no case, but are prepositional groups that contain an inner nominal group that has a case ruled by the preposition.)

"... the main verb is the king of its sentence ..." -- I like the way you phrased this. Another way of putting it: "The verb is sun of a sentence, and the other parts are merely planets orbiting around it." Some grammars, I think influenced more by formal logic than by any natural language, make the subject king, with everything else called the "predicate". But German, more than most other languages, seems to break this model.

As always, spot on and completely informative. Thank you.

@RDBury: In English grammar the predicate is anything but the subject. German grammar has a different approach: In German only the verb and some other words that are directly connected to the verb belong to the predicate. Anything else are objects, with the subject as a very special object.
